# Convexity of Cartesian Product space

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose, $X$ and $Y$ are two sets whose cartesian product $X\times Y$ is convex, can I say that both $X$ and $Y$ are convex? If no, could you give an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It follows by linearity of the projection maps.

Comment: Looks OK and $\sin^2(\pi/2)$. -- From [Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1159365).